# flutter code display error in visual studio code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

Initially this code is correct but after I reinstalled Windows and its applications, the project that was correct is now an error.

[My project error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsJYc.png)

flutter doctor -v :

```
[√] Flutter (Channel dev, 1.26.0-1.0.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.804], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.26.0-1.0.pre at F:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision 63062a6443 (9 weeks ago), 2020-12-13 23:19:13 +0800
    • Engine revision 4797b06652
    • Dart version 2.12.0 (build 2.12.0-141.0.dev)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at F:\src\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.53.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\hyda\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.19.0

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • sdk gphone x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: have you installed flutter plugin ?

Comment: try to re-install flutter plugin in your VSCode.

Comment: Restart VSCode!

Comment: CMD: flutter upgrade

Answer (score 0):

The error you get is because the libraries are not loaded. First, go to the **pubseck.yaml** file and get the packages there. If still not working see this command

-> flutter clean
-> flutter pub get

Answer (score 0):

Such problems can be solved by running this command:

```
flutter clean
```

Once that is done, go to pubspec.yaml and check if all the packages are still there. For cross-checking, run:

```
flutter pub get
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: I had 230 errors, from the cleaning I got 16k errors, then reduced to 1 error 7 warning 81 info